# Building CustomAuthorization in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, authorization, custom-attributes

In the `DB` i have `Role` and `User` entities with one to many relationship.

What i am trying to do is to build custom authorization filter. All the tutorials that i have seen are using default `ASP.NET` membership. All i know is that i need to inherit `AuthorizationAttribute` but do not know which methods do i need to override and how to implement them.

```
public class UserAuth : AuthorizeAttribute
{

}
```

In the `DB`:

**Role**

```
public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RolenameValue { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // // // // //

    public Rolename Rolename 
    {
        get { return (ProjectName.Domain.Enums.Rolename)RolenameValue; }
        set { RolenameValue = (int)value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

**User**

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(5)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

    public int GenderValue { get; set; }

    // // // // // // //

    public Gender Gender
    {
        get { return (ProjectName.Domain.Enums.Gender)GenderValue; }
        set { GenderValue = (int)value; }
    }

    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleID")]
    public Role Role { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to create a custom attribute. You can use existing `AuthoriseAttribute` but what you should do is implement custom `Principal` class that will use your own roles from DB. In your `Principal` class you will implement IsInRole method:

```
public bool IsInRole(string role)
{
    if(this.Roles == null)
        this.Roles = DependencyResolver.Current
           .GetService<ISecurityService>()
           .GetUserPermissions(this.Identity.Name);

    return this.Roles.Any(p => p.Name == role);
}
```

You should set your custom `Principal` in Global.asax

```
    void OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // Get a reference to the current User 
        IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User; 

        // If we are dealing with an authenticated forms authentication request         
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated && user.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms") 
        { 
            // Create custom Principal 
            var principal = new MyCustomPrincipal(user.Identity); 

            // Attach the Principal to HttpContext.User and Thread.CurrentPrincipal 
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal; 
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1, I do it in the same way, except that I load all roles through my Authorization repository in `OnPostAtuthenticate`.

Comment: How to implement `MyCustomPrincipal`? :P

EDIT: I mean, how to properly implement it. Only with `IsInRole()` ?

Comment: Derive from `GenericPrincipal` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericprincipal.aspx) or implement `IPrincipal` interface