# Multiple Authorization attributes on method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm having trouble specifying two separate Authorization attributes on a class method: the user is to be allowed access if either of the two attributes are true.

The Athorization class looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {
. . .
```

and the action:

```
[Auth(Roles = AuthRole.SuperAdministrator)]
[Auth(Roles = AuthRole.Administrator, Module = ModuleID.SomeModule)]
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View(GetIndexViewModel());
}
```

Is there a way to solve this or do I need to rethink my approach?

This is to be run in MVC2.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Multiple `AuthorizeAttribute` instances are processed by MVC as if they were joined with `AND`. If you want an `OR` behaviour you will need to implement your own logic for checks. Preferably implement `AuthAttribute` to take multiple roles and perform an own check with `OR` logic.

Another solution is to use standard `AuthorizeAttribute` and implement custom `IPrincipal` that will implement `bool IsInRole(string role)` method to provide 'OR' behaviour.

An example is here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10754108/449906

Comment: Would it be possible to create another Authorization attribute (i.e. `public class MultipleAuthOrAttribute {`) that would take as input several `AuthAttributes`?

Comment: You cannot create an Attribute that takes instances of other Attributes. Attribute class constructor can only accept compile-time valid values / primitive types. That's why `AuthorizeAttribute` takes Roles as a string.

Comment: Can someone provide a reference to official documentation that supports the statement that multiple `AuthorizeAttribute` instances are processed as a logical `AND`. In my own tests, it appears that the order of the filters is important, with the first filter having the final say of whether authentication succeeds.

Comment: See my answer for a way to get `OR` logic with multiple `AuthorizationHandler`s in asp.net core.

Answer (score 91):

There is a better way to do this in later versions of asp.net you can do both OR and AND on roles. This is done through convention, listing multiple roles in a single Authorize will perform an OR where adding Multiple Authorize Attributes will perform AND.

OR example

```
[Authorize(Roles = "PowerUser,ControlPanelUser")]
```

AND Example

```
[Authorize(Roles = "PowerUser")]
[Authorize(Roles = "ControlPanelUser")]
```

You can find more info on this at the following link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles

Comment: The OR examaple also works for .NET Framework (not core)!

Comment: It seems Roles are there, but not Policies (only Policy)

Answer (score 9):

I've been using this solution in production environment for awhile now, using .NET Core 3.0. I wanted the OR behavior between a **custom attribute** and the native `AuthorizeAttribute`. To do so, I implemented the `IAuthorizationEvaluator` interface, **which gets called as soon as all authorizers evaluate theirs results**.

```
/// <summary>
/// Responsible for evaluating if authorization was successful or not, after execution of
/// authorization handler pipelines.
/// This class was implemented because MVC default behavior is to apply an AND behavior
/// with the result of each authorization handler. But to allow our API to have multiple
/// authorization handlers, in which the final authorization result is if ANY handlers return
/// true, the class <cref name="IAuthorizationEvaluator" /> had to be extended to add this
/// OR behavior.
/// </summary>
public class CustomAuthorizationEvaluator : IAuthorizationEvaluator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Evaluates the results of all authorization handlers called in the pipeline.
    /// Will fail if: at least ONE authorization handler calls context.Fail() OR none of
    /// authorization handlers call context.Success().
    /// Will succeed if: at least one authorization handler calls context.Success().
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">Shared context among handlers.</param>
    /// <returns>Authorization result.</returns>
    public AuthorizationResult Evaluate(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        // If context.Fail() got called in ANY of the authorization handlers:
        if (context.HasFailed == true)
        {
            return AuthorizationResult.Failed(AuthorizationFailure.ExplicitFail());
        }

        // If none handler called context.Fail(), some of them could have called
        // context.Success(). MVC treats the context.HasSucceeded with an AND behavior,
        // meaning that if one of the custom authorization handlers have called 
        // context.Success() and others didn't, the property context.HasSucceeded will be
        // false. Thus, this class is responsible for applying the OR behavior instead of
        // the default AND.

        bool success = 
            context.PendingRequirements.Count() < context.Requirements.Count();

        return success == true 
            ? AuthorizationResult.Success()
            : AuthorizationResult.Failed(AuthorizationFailure.ExplicitFail());
    }
}
```

This evaluator will only be called if added to .NET service collection (in your startup class) as follows:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationEvaluator, CustomAuthorizationEvaluator>();
```

In the controller class, decorate each method with both attributes. In my case `[Authorize]` and `[CustomAuthorize]`.

Comment: In NET Core 8 this wont work correctly. It will still use AND logic.
Because HasFailed will be true, if at least one Requirement already called Fail().

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how others feel about this but I wanted an `OR` behavior too.  In my `AuthorizationHandler`s I just called `Succeed` if any of them passed.  Note this did NOT work with the built-in `Authorize` attribute that has no parameters.

```
public class LoggedInHandler : AuthorizationHandler<LoggedInAuthReq>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    public LoggedInHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, LoggedInAuthReq requirement)
    {
        var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        if (httpContext != null && requirement.IsLoggedIn())
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            foreach (var req in context.Requirements)
            {
                context.Succeed(req);
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Supply your own LoggedInAuthReq.  In startup inject these in services with

```
        services.AddAuthorization(o => {
            o.AddPolicy("AadLoggedIn", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new LoggedInAuthReq()));
            ... more here
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, LoggedInHandler>();
        ... more here
```

And in your controller method

```
    [Authorize("FacebookLoggedIn")]
    [Authorize("MsaLoggedIn")]
    [Authorize("AadLoggedIn")]
    [HttpGet("anyuser")]
    public JsonResult AnyUser()
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { I = "did it with Any User!" })
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
        };
    }
```

This could probably also be accomplished with a single attribute and a bunch of `if` statements.  It `works for me` in this scenario. asp.net core 2.2 as of this writing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core/60554899#60554899  This question also has some useful info that I have incorporated into our login process.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `DefaultAuthorizationEvaluator` with this one to get it work with `OR` logic instead of default `AND` logic, to get it work on NET Core 8.

```
/// <summary>
/// Allow our API to have OR behavior with multiple authorization handlers,
/// in which the final authorization result is if ANY handlers return true.
/// This class was implemented because default behavior is to apply an AND behavior
/// with the result of each authorization handler.
/// </summary>
public class AppAuthorizationEvaluator : IAuthorizationEvaluator
{
    public AuthorizationResult Evaluate(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        int totalRequirementsCount = context.Requirements.Count();

        // HasFailed will be true, if at least one requirement already called Fail()
        if (totalRequirementsCount <= 1)
        {
            return DefaultEvaluate(context);
        }

        var failedRequirements = context.PendingRequirements;

        bool isAllRequirementsFailed = totalRequirementsCount == failedRequirements.Count();

        if (isAllRequirementsFailed)
        {
            return DefaultEvaluate(context);
        }

        return AuthorizationResult.Success();
    }

    // Logic from DefaultAuthorizationEvaluator
    private static AuthorizationResult DefaultEvaluate(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        return context.HasSucceeded
            ? AuthorizationResult.Success()
            : AuthorizationResult.Failed(context.HasFailed
                ? AuthorizationFailure.Failed(context.FailureReasons)
                : AuthorizationFailure.Failed(context.PendingRequirements));
    }
}
```

And register it in `Program/Startup` by DI:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationEvaluator, CustomAuthorizationEvaluator>();
```

This is my working Answer inspired by [ceres-rohana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6775197/ceres-rohana). Fixing his version to work in NET Core 8.