# How do you create a custom AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I'm trying to make a custom authorization attribute in ASP.NET Core.  In previous versions it was possible to override `bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)`.  But this no longer exists in [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/3a8ea672eae590785a78d74777abb76bb9664130/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization/AuthorizeAttribute.cs).

What is the current approach to make a custom AuthorizeAttribute?

What I am trying to accomplish: I am receiving a session ID in the Header Authorization. From that ID I'll know whether a particular action is valid.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it, but MVC is open source.  You could pull the github repo and look for implementations of IAuthorizationFilter.  If I have time today I'll look for you and post an actual answer, but no promises.  github repo:  https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc

Comment: OK, out of time, but look for usages of AuthorizationPolicy in the MVC Repo, which uses AuthorizeAttribute, in the aspnet/Security repo, here:  https://github.com/aspnet/Security.  Alternately, look in the MVC repo for the namespace where the security stuff you care about seems to reside, which is Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization.  Sorry I can't be more helpful.  Good luck!

Answer (score 727, accepted):

The approach recommended by the ASP.Net Core team is to use the new policy design which is fully documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/).  The basic idea behind the new approach is to use the new `[Authorize]` attribute to designate a "policy" (e.g. `[Authorize( Policy = "YouNeedToBe18ToDoThis")]` where the policy is registered in the application's `Startup.cs` to execute some block of code (i.e. ensure the user has an age claim where the age is 18 or older).

The policy design is a great addition to the framework and the ASP.Net Security Core team should be commended for its introduction.  That said, it isn't well-suited for all cases.  The shortcoming of this approach is that it fails to provide a convenient solution for the most common need of simply asserting that a given controller or action requires a given claim type.  In the case where an application may have hundreds of discrete permissions governing CRUD operations on individual REST resources ("CanCreateOrder", "CanReadOrder", "CanUpdateOrder", "CanDeleteOrder", etc.), the new approach either requires repetitive one-to-one mappings between a policy name and a claim name (e.g. `options.AddPolicy("CanUpdateOrder", policy => policy.RequireClaim(MyClaimTypes.Permission, "CanUpdateOrder));`), or writing some code to perform these registrations at run time (e.g. read all claim types from a database and perform the aforementioned call in a loop).  The problem with this approach for the majority of cases is that it's unnecessary overhead.

While the ASP.Net Core Security team recommends never creating your own solution, in some cases this may be the most prudent option with which to start.

The following is an implementation which uses the `IAuthorizationFilter` to provide a simple way to express a claim requirement for a given controller or action:

```
public class ClaimRequirementAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public ClaimRequirementAttribute(string claimType, string claimValue) : base(typeof(ClaimRequirementFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] {new Claim(claimType, claimValue) };
    }
}

public class ClaimRequirementFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    readonly Claim _claim;

    public ClaimRequirementFilter(Claim claim)
    {
        _claim = claim;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var hasClaim = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.Any(c => c.Type == _claim.Type && c.Value == _claim.Value);
        if (!hasClaim)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}


[Route("api/resource")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [ClaimRequirement(MyClaimTypes.Permission, "CanReadResource")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetResource()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: HOw would one register the ClaimRequirementFilter? Is it handled automatically?

Comment: Weird that someone deleted the comments from all the answers here.  Anyway, there is no registration required.  The framework automatically invokes the filter by virtue of it extending TypeFilterAttribute.

Comment: This is great! Works in a controller. How to check in a Razor page?

Comment: This approach is returning an `InvalidOperationException` if I do `context.Result = new ForbiddenResult();` how are we supposed to do this in dotnet 6?

Comment: As it is not possible to register all policies, there exists IAuthorizationPolicyProvider. You need to implement it. Please refer to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: How does this work with multiple schemes?

Comment: @jixtra You can include any logic you need in a filter.  Are you wanting to perform logic based on current authorization filters?  If so, you should be able to retrieve that by injecting IAuthenticationSchemeProvider.

Comment: The one thing missing in this solution is that you cannot use as Task based method inside  the AuthorizationFilter since it doesn't provide a Task based interface to implement.

Comment: If you need async behavior, you'd implement IAsyncAuthorizationFilter

Comment: This works perfectly, but how would one use this in the view when needed?

Comment: After I tried all possible options: custom IAuthorizationFilter, custom IAuthorizationPolicyProvider for dynamic policy, custom attribute,... in few days and with writing unit test. Our finial solution is using requirement with static policy. We also can use IAuthorizationPolicyProvider but we have to implement caching policy, because we store some cooked meta-data on IAuthorizationRequirement for next time check access also. That is blowdart answer below [I'm the asp.net security person...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465227/3737294)

Comment: I was looking for exactly same thing..!! Perfectly working for me without modifying Program files.

Comment: @DerekGreer if we have, for example, 50 claims that we want to check in `Authorize` attribute, would we create 50 policies or do a custom attribute implementation? what would be a recommended way for that?

Comment: The most straightforward way is to use `GetEndpont` method from `HttpContext` as suggested by @rtype

Comment: Thank you for THE definitive way to customize authorization

Answer (score 320):

I'm the asp.net security person. <s>Firstly let me apologize that none of this is documented yet outside of the music store sample or unit tests, and it's all still being refined in terms of exposed APIs.</s> Detailed documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/).

We don't want you writing custom authorize attributes. If you need to do that we've done something wrong. Instead, you should be writing authorization *requirements*.

Authorization acts upon Identities. Identities are created by authentication.

You say in comments you want to check a session ID in a header. Your session ID would be the basis for identity. If you wanted to use the `Authorize` attribute you'd write an authentication middleware to take that header and turn it into an authenticated `ClaimsPrincipal`. You would then check that inside an authorization requirement. Authorization requirements can be as complicated as you like, for example here's one that takes a date of birth claim on the current identity and will authorize if the user is over 18;

```
public class Over18Requirement : AuthorizationHandler<Over18Requirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
  public override void Handle(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, Over18Requirement requirement)
  {
    if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth))
    {
      context.Fail();
      return;
    }

    var dobVal = context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth).Value;
    var dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(dobVal);
    int age = DateTime.Today.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;
    if (dateOfBirth > DateTime.Today.AddYears(-age))
    {
      age--;
    }

    if (age >= 18)
    {
      context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
    else
    {
      context.Fail();
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your `ConfigureServices()` function you'd wire it up

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Over18", 
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new Authorization.Over18Requirement()));
});
```

And finally, apply it to a controller or action method with

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Over18")]
```

Comment: I have to comment that, all this is more complex than implementing a custom authorization method. I know how I want authorization to be done I could just go and write it in MVC 5, in MVC 6 they add a lot of "done" code that is actually more complex to understand than implementing the core "thing" itself. Gets me sitting in front of a page trying to figure something out instead of writing code right through, also a big pain for people who use RDBMS other than Microsoft's (or No-Sql).

Comment: I, like many others in these comments, am very disappointed that using attributes for authorization has been so greatly neutered over what was possible in Web API 2. Sorry guys, but your "requirement" abstraction fails to cover any case where we could previously use attribute constructor parameters to inform an underlying authorization algorithm. It used to be brain-dead simple to do something like `[CustomAuthorize(Operator.And, Permission.GetUser, Permission.ModifyUser)]`. I could use a single custom attribute in an infinite number of ways simply by modifying the constructor parameters.

Comment: I am also shocked that the self-proclaimed "Lead ASP.NET security guy" is actually suggesting to use magic strings (hacking the meaning of `IAuthorizeData.Policy`) and custom policy providers to overcome this blatant oversight, rather than addressing it within the framework. I thought we weren't supposed to be creating our own implementations? You've left several of us no choice except to re-implement authorization from scratch (again), and this time without even the benefit of Web API's old `Authorize` attribute. Now we have to do it on the action filter or middleware level.

Comment: “Life is really simple, but we insist on making it complicated.” - Confucious

Comment: What about using dependent services here ? How can they be used within the handler ...?

Comment: Is it possible to use enums for the Policy names instead of strings?

Comment: I have just found out that actions can't override the policies of the controller (I stand corrected), which forces me to create my own attribute. Please don't force us to stick to a limited way of doing things - you can't possibly foresee all the scenarios you need to cater for, so provide for flexibility. Development is not a religion - "best practice" can change over time and isn't a rule, it's just a guideline.

Comment: Hello. In my case, I am developing an application that I need to authorize users by module. An administrator is able to set which modules a user has access to. That authorization will be saved in database. I don't see other way to accomplish this besides creating a custom AuthorizationAttribute. Do you?

Comment: @jstuardo there’s nothing wrong with implementing your own Attribute inheriting from the base AuthorizeAttribute overriding what you need; it is by design a valid approach and how you can then implement your own constructor injected values, enums (to stop using magic strings), etc. But do not implement your authorization logic in the Attribute — that is wrong and has numerous issues. The Attribute should only contain configuration of the auth settings (eg perhaps a Module Enum that is then set into the Roles), all logic to enforce this should be done in Middleware or in a Filter.

Comment: @jstuardo but if you can leverage the existing Roles or Policy approach then no custom middleware or filter is needed. For example just set the correct role claims on your user, configure your custom Attribute to store the valid/acceptable on the base Attributes Roles collection and it will work.

Answer (score 179):

It seems that with ASP.NET Core 2, you can again inherit `AuthorizeAttribute`, you just need to also implement `IAuthorizationFilter` (or `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string _someFilterParameter;

    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string someFilterParameter)
    {
        _someFilterParameter = someFilterParameter;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // it isn't needed to set unauthorized result 
            // as the base class already requires the user to be authenticated
            // this also makes redirect to a login page work properly
            // context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }

        // you can also use registered services
        var someService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ISomeService>();

        var isAuthorized = someService.IsUserAuthorized(user.Identity.Name, _someFilterParameter);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you can only use this to _deny_ authorization, not _grant_ it?

Comment: @MEMark By *granting*, you mean overriding another authorization attribute?

Comment: I guess you could put it like that. I mean effectively allowing access to the resource.

Comment: AFAIK, access is allowed by default, so you need to explicitly deny it (e.g., by adding an AuthorizeAttribute). Check this question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272422/multiple-authorization-attributes-on-method

Comment: Also note, in suggested example one doesn't have to inherit from AuthorizeAttribute. You can inherit from **Attribute** and **IAuthorizationFilter**. This way you wouldn't get the following exception if some non-standard authentication mechanism is used:
**InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.**

Comment: @Anatolyevich I still receive that error if I choose to do a `context.Result = new ForbidResult();`. But I'm liking this option so far.

Comment: Note that if your `OnAuthorization` implementation needs to await an async method, you should implement `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` instead of `IAuthorizationFilter` otherwise your filter will execute synchronously and your controller action will execute regardless of the outcome of the filter.

Comment: I wanted to deny expired tokens, but accept anonymus as well, this helped me return unauthorized if the token is expired but accept no token. Thanks, this helped a lot

Comment: Hey @Anatolyevich can you explain what's the difference between inheriting from `Attribute` instead of `AuthorizeAttribute` in this case. What's the reason why we get the `InvalidOperationException: No authenticationSchema was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.` when inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute` and implementing `IAuthorizationFilter`? Thanks!

Comment: @Tom That comment was from 2.5 years ago. I don't remember. =)

Comment: Thanks for this. My simple scenario was "if Request is a preflight `OPTIONS` then respond with some headers and quit" and MS's "official way" is way overengineered to do this simple thing.

Comment: using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;  For using T? GetService<T>

Comment: The one thing missing in this solution is that you cannot use as Task based method inside  the AuthorizationFilter since it doesn't provide a Task based interface to implement.

Comment: @PeterBons Have you checked `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `_someFilterParameter` is set during app startup, but in `OnAuthorization()` I have always null in `_someFilterParameter`. .NET 6

Answer (score 80):

Based on Derek Greer **GREAT** answer, i did it with enums.

Here is an example of my code:

```
public enum PermissionItem
{
    User,
    Product,
    Contact,
    Review,
    Client
}

public enum PermissionAction
{
    Read,
    Create,
}


public class AuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeAttribute(PermissionItem item, PermissionAction action)
    : base(typeof(AuthorizeActionFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { item, action };
    }
}

public class AuthorizeActionFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly PermissionItem _item;
    private readonly PermissionAction _action;
    public AuthorizeActionFilter(PermissionItem item, PermissionAction action)
    {
        _item = item;
        _action = action;
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = MumboJumboFunction(context.HttpContext.User, _item, _action); // :)

        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}

public class UserController : BaseController
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public UserController( DbContext context) :
        base()
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Authorize(PermissionItem.User, PermissionAction.Read)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.User.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I created this post with a slightly different implementation and a request for validation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551047/custom-bearer-token-authorization-for-asp-net-core

Comment: U didnt show in your answer  how one would apply this to the user ie how did u store the permission bit against the current user

Comment: @rogue39nin, you can use Claims (context.HttpContext.User.Claims) to add some extra **public** metadata to your token. You can also use database, call external services or any other methods that allow you to get that information.

Comment: @bruno.almeida, this works great. How would I use it in a Razor view though?

Comment: Just info for blazor user; This IAuthorizationFilter and TypeFilterAttribute don't work in blazor, I already tried, and IAuhtorizationFilter never get called.

Comment: How to filter the authentication scheme with this pattern?

Comment: The one thing missing in this solution is that you cannot use as Task based method inside  the AuthorizationFilter since it doesn't provide a Task based interface to implement.

Answer (score 59):

You can create your own AuthorizationHandler that will find custom attributes on your Controllers and Actions, and pass them to the HandleRequirementAsync method.

```
public abstract class AttributeAuthorizationHandler<TRequirement, TAttribute> : AuthorizationHandler<TRequirement> where TRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TRequirement requirement)
    {
        var attributes = new List<TAttribute>();

        var action = (context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext)?.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        if (action != null)
        {
            attributes.AddRange(GetAttributes(action.ControllerTypeInfo.UnderlyingSystemType));
            attributes.AddRange(GetAttributes(action.MethodInfo));
        }

        return HandleRequirementAsync(context, requirement, attributes);
    }

    protected abstract Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TRequirement requirement, IEnumerable<TAttribute> attributes);

    private static IEnumerable<TAttribute> GetAttributes(MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
        return memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false).Cast<TAttribute>();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it for any custom attributes you need on your controllers or actions. For example to add permission requirements. Just create your custom attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class PermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public PermissionAttribute(string name) : base("Permission")
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Then create a Requirement to add to your Policy

```
public class PermissionAuthorizationRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    //Add any custom requirement properties if you have them
}
```

Then create the AuthorizationHandler for your custom attribute, inheriting the AttributeAuthorizationHandler that we created earlier. It will be passed an IEnumerable for all your custom attributes in the HandleRequirementsAsync method, accumulated from your Controller and Action.

```
public class PermissionAuthorizationHandler : AttributeAuthorizationHandler<PermissionAuthorizationRequirement, PermissionAttribute>
{
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionAuthorizationRequirement requirement, IEnumerable<PermissionAttribute> attributes)
    {
        foreach (var permissionAttribute in attributes)
        {
            if (!await AuthorizeAsync(context.User, permissionAttribute.Name))
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }

    private Task<bool> AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, string permission)
    {
        //Implement your custom user permission logic here
    }
}
```

And finally, in your Startup.cs ConfigureServices method, add your custom AuthorizationHandler to the services, and add your Policy.

```
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionAuthorizationHandler>();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Permission", policyBuilder =>
            {
                policyBuilder.Requirements.Add(new PermissionAuthorizationRequirement());
            });
        });
```

Now you can simply decorate your Controllers and Actions with your custom attribute.

```
[Permission("AccessCustomers")]
public class CustomersController
{
    [Permission("AddCustomer")]
    IActionResult AddCustomer([FromBody] Customer customer)
    {
        //Add customer
    }
}
```

Comment: This is quite overengineered... I solved the same using a simple AuthorizationFilterAttribute wich receives a parameter. You don't need reflection for this, it seems even more artificious than the "official" solution (that I find quite poor).

Comment: @Vi100 I couldn't find much information on AuthorizationFilters in ASP.NET Core. The official documentation page says they are currently working on this topic.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/authorization-filters

Comment: @Vi100 Can you please share your solution, if there is a simpler way to achieve this I would love to know.

Comment: I actually like this solution, it leverages the new policy system and combines Attributes to provide a pretty clean solution. I use a global Authorize attribute to ensure the user is logged in, then apply a permission policy where required.

Comment: One thing to note the use of UnderlyingSystemType above does not compile, but removing it seems to work.

Comment: I'm trying this solution out, but in `HandleRequirementAsync` the `action` property becomes null, and then no attributes get set.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64247810/1813326

Comment: This solution is great. Reminds me of the IdentityServer3 ResourceAuthorization. It looks like AuthorizeAsync handles the permission checking logic. Do you have example use cases for what PermissionAuthorizationRequirement would be used for? Going to policy based requirements is new for me.

Comment: @gilm0079 Requirements are, typically, declarative ways to specifying what needs to be fulfilled for a given Policy. This example is a bit different because the `PermissionAuthorizationRequirement` is not specifying the requirement data, instead it is being used to "glue" a Policy (`"Permission"`) to a Requirement Handler (`PermissionAuthorizationHandler`).

In this example, the attributes are storing the declarative requirements, instead of having 100s of specific Requirement <-> Policy mappings.

Comment: How to use this with multiple schemes?

Comment: I'm returning `return new Task<bool>(() => { return true; });` in the `AuthorizeAsync()` as a test. But it seems afterwards it gets stuck and nothing happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: I like this solution, but in PermissionAuthorizationHandler the attributes always = 0, could someone help me in figure it out, why?

Comment: I found why because I use Blazor and Blazor uses Components no Controllers in this case
 var action = (context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext)?.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

Comment: For Blazor needs to use this one    
var pageTypeList = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(PermissionAttribute)) != null);

Answer (score 41):

I decided to add another simple answer. B/c I find most of these answers a little overengineered. And also because I needed a way to GRANT authorization, not just DENY it. Most of the answers here offer a way to "tighten" security, but I wanted to "loosen" it. For example: "if some application setting is configured, then allow access to anonymous users".

```
public class MyAuthAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        //check access 
        if (CheckPermissions())
        {
            //all good, add optional code if you want. Or don't
        }
        else
        {
            //DENIED!
            //return "ChallengeResult" to redirect to login page (for example)
            context.Result = new ChallengeResult(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
}
```

### That's it.

No need to mess with "policies", "claims", "handlers" and other [beep]

Usage:

```
// GET api/Get/5
[MyAuth]
public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
{
    return "blahblah";
}
```

#### A little (optional) update from 2024

@Nikstr has asked in the comments how to use dependency injection with this. Check it out:

```
//basically same class as above, but just a filter, not an attribute
public class MyAuthFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private SomeService _service; //let's say you need a service for your auth

    //dependency ibjection in constructor
    public MyAuthAttribute(SomeService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        //check access 
        if (CheckPermissions())
        {
            //all good, add optional code if you want. Or don't
        }
        else
        {
            //DENIED!
            context.Result = new ChallengeResult(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
}
```

Now make sure you register this service in Startup.cs somethinng like `.AddScoped(blahblah)`

However usage is slightly different:

```
// GET api/Get/5
[TypeFilter<MyAuthFilter>] // <-- note this
public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
```

`TypeFilter` simply tells the Framework to instantiate the attirbute every time and use DI when doing so. Just google for "TypeFilterAttribute" docs for more info

### P.S.

If you don't like the uglyness of this line `[TypeFilter<MyAuthFilter>]` you can simply inherit from `TypeFilter` like this

```
//empty one-liner "wrapper" class that does nothing
public class MyAuthAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute<MyAuthFilter> { }
```

And then use it like before

```
[MyAuth] // <-- looks simpler huh
public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
```

Comment: Thank you, at last a simple solution! Quite hard to find among all the over-engineered mess.

Comment: The one thing missing in this solution is that you cannot use as Task based method inside  the AuthorizationFilter since it doesn't provide a Task based interface to implement. That is why this very simple solution doesn't always work

Comment: @PeterBons for async - use `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter`

Comment: Seems the major drawback of filters that we cannot use DI - meaning, normally, not in hacky way.

Comment: @Niksr I just updated the answer for DI., Check it out. Sorry it took me forever to notice your comment

Answer (score 31):

> What is the current approach to make a custom AuthorizeAttribute

For pure authorization scenarios (like restricting access to specific users only), the recommended approach is to use the new authorization block: https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/1c0aeb08bb1ebd846726232226279bbe001782e1/samples/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L84-L92

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<AuthorizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ManageStore", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Action", "ManageStore"));
        });
    }
}

public class StoreController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Policy = "ManageStore"), HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Manage() { ... }
}
```

For authentication, it's best handled at the middleware level.

What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I am receiving a session ID in the Header Authorization.  From that ID I'll know whether a particular action is valid.

Comment: Then that's not an authorization concern. I guess your "session ID" is actually a token containing the identity of the caller: this should definitely be done at the middleware level.

Comment: It isn't authentication (establishing who the user is) but it is authorization (determining if a user should have access to a resource).  So where are you suggesting I look to solve this?

Comment: Curious: how are you creating your session identifiers?

Comment: @jltrem, agreed, what you are talking about is authorization, not authentication.

Comment: @Pinpoint I'm not creating them.  I'm just the guy in the middle providing access to another system.

Comment: @EricBurcham a session identifier is definitely a way to identity (= authenticate) a user, I'm afraid.

Comment: @jltrem but you're extracting some information from the identifier to determine who's the caller, right?

Comment: @Pinpoint I am not. I query another system for that info. That system authenticates (determines the user) and authorizes (tells me what that user can access).  Right now I have it hacked to work by calling a method in each controller action to have the other system verify the session. I'd like to have this automatically happen via an attribute.

Comment: `I am not. I query another system for that info`... well, you're asking an external provider to authenticate your users, but that's exactly the same thing, I'm afraid. You should consider creating a new middleware for the external authentication part (it would query your remote system and retrieve user's identity before creating a new ClaimsPrincipal containing the roles or the actions the user is allowed to query) and adding a new authorization policy to ensure the caller has a role/claim allowing him/her to make the request.

Comment: Meanwhile this can be related to the question, is misspointed, and should be a comment at least.

Answer (score 20):

The modern way is AuthenticationHandlers

in startup.cs add

```
services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication").AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null);

public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public BasicAuthenticationHandler(
            IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            UrlEncoder encoder,
            ISystemClock clock,
            IUserService userService)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing Authorization Header");

            User user = null;
            try
            {
                var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers["Authorization"]);
                var credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Parameter);
                var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(credentialBytes).Split(new[] { ':' }, 2);
                var username = credentials[0];
                var password = credentials[1];
                user = await _userService.Authenticate(username, password);
            }
            catch
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authorization Header");
            }

            if (user == null)
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid User-name or Password");

            var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
            };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE .NET 8**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

namespace LicenseWeppApp.Infrastructure;
internal class CustomBasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> _options;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly UrlEncoder _encoder;
    IUserService _userService;

    public CustomBasicAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, IUserService userService)
        : base(options, logger, encoder)
    {
        _options = options;
        _logger = logger.CreateLogger("LicenseWeppApp.Infrastructure.CustomBasicAuthenticationHandler");//create a logger like this if you use obfuscation
        _encoder = encoder;
        _userService = userService;

    }
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {

        if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues value) || value.Count == 0)
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing Authorization Header");

        User? user = null;
        try
        {
            var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(value);
            var credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Parameter);
            var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(credentialBytes).Split(':', 2);
            var username = credentials[0];
            var password = credentials[1];
            user = await _userService.Authenticate(username, password);
        }
        catch
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Invalid Authorization Header {value}", value.ToString());
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authorization Header");
        }

        if (user == null)
            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid User-name or Password");

        var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, value:user.ID.ToString()),
                new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.Name, value:user.UserName),
        };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

        return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

    }
}
```

IUserService is a service that you make where you have user name and password.
basically it returns a user class that you use to map your claims on.

```
var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
            };
```

Then you can query these claims and her any data you mapped, ther are quite a few, have a look at ClaimTypes class

you can use this in an extension method an get any of the mappings

```
public int? GetUserId()
{
   if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
       var id=context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
       if (!(id is null) && int.TryParse(id.Value, out var userId))
            return userId;
     }
      return new Nullable<int>();
 }
```

This new way, i think is better than the old way as shown here, both work

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization != null)
        {
            var authToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
            // decoding authToken we get decode value in 'Username:Password' format
            var decodeauthToken = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authToken));
            // spliting decodeauthToken using ':'
            var arrUserNameandPassword = decodeauthToken.Split(':');
            // at 0th postion of array we get username and at 1st we get password
            if (IsAuthorizedUser(arrUserNameandPassword[0], arrUserNameandPassword[1]))
            {
                // setting current principle
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(arrUserNameandPassword[0]), null);
            }
            else
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }

    public static bool IsAuthorizedUser(string Username, string Password)
    {
        // In this method we can handle our database logic here...
        return Username.Equals("test") && Password == "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: This brilliant answer just works like a charm! Thank you for that and I wish you it will get upvoted, as it is the best answer I have found after like a six hours of searching through blogs, documentation and stack for Basic authentication plus Role authorization.

Comment: @PiotrŚródka, you are welcome, please note that the answer is a little "simplified", test if you have a ':' in the text as a malicious user could try and crash your service by simply not playing nice ending in an index out of range exception. as always test what is given to you by external sources

Comment: This was really helpful.  The other thing I needed to do was make sure app.UseAuthentication(); was before app.UseAuthorization();

Comment: What if I wanted to call an external authentication where I get a token that has an expiration time? How would I handle the authorization? In your case you make a call to the database to retrieve the user, if not retrieved then the user is unauthorized. I want to do this with a token but I dont want to save it in the database.

Comment: @Florent, the code you like to execute is your, how you compare it is yours, feel free to call any service you like

Comment: @RosdiKasim: And yet it inherits from AuthorizationFilterAttribute.

Comment: I'm not an expert but it seems to me that this answer confuses authentication with authorization. The `CustomBasicAuthenticationHandler` is as, the name suggests, verifying that a correct username and password has been provided. That is authentication. What the `AuthorizeAttribute` does, and what the OP appears to be asking about, is control access to a particulr resouce within the application. That is authorization, and creating a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` is still the most suitable approach.

Answer (score 11):

If anyone just wants to validate a bearer token in the authorize phase using the current security practices you can,

add this to your Startup/ConfigureServices

```
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, BearerAuthorizationHandler>();
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer();

    services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("Bearer",
        policy => policy.AddRequirements(new BearerRequirement())
        )
    );
```

and this in your codebase,

```
public class BearerRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public async Task<bool> IsTokenValid(SomeValidationContext context, string token)
    {
        // here you can check if the token received is valid 
        return true;
    }
}

public class BearerAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<BearerRequirement> 
{

    public BearerAuthorizationHandler(SomeValidationContext thatYouCanInject)
    {
       ...
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, BearerRequirement requirement)
    {
        var authFilterCtx = (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext)context.Resource;
        string authHeader = authFilterCtx.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.Contains("Bearer"))
        {
            var token = authHeader.Replace("Bearer ", string.Empty);
            if (await requirement.IsTokenValid(thatYouCanInject, token))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the code doesn't reach `context.Succeed(...)` it will Fail anyway (401).

And then in your controllers you can use

```
 [Authorize(Policy = "Bearer", AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Comment: Why would you choose to perform your own validation of the token when the JwtBearer middleware already takes care of this?  It also puts the correct content in the WWW-Authenticate response header for an auth/token validation/expiration failure.  If you want access to the authentication pipeline there are specific events you can tap into on AddJwtBearer options (OnAuthenticationFailed, OnChallenge, OnMessageReceived and OnTokenValidated).

Comment: This is infinitely simpler than any other solution I've seen.  Especially for simple api key use cases.  One update: for 3.1 the cast to AuthorizationFilterContext is no longer valid because of the endpoint routing stuff.  You need to grab the context via HttpContextAccessor.

Answer (score 9):

The below code worked for me in .Net Core 5

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AccessAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public string Module { get; set; } //Permission string to get from controller

    public AccessAuthorizationAttribute(string module)
    {
        Module = module;
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        //Validate if any permissions are passed when using attribute at controller or action level

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Module))
        {
            //Validation cannot take place without any permissions so returning unauthorized
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }
       
        if (hasAccess)
        {
            return;
        }

        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: When authorization fails, you want to return 403, not 401.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348219/4974715) is not realistically maintainable or suitable because "CanReadResource" is being used as a claim (but should essentially be a policy in reality, IMO). The approach at the answer is not OK in the way it was used, because if an action method requires many different claims setups, then with that answer you would have to repeatedly write something like...

```
[ClaimRequirement(MyClaimTypes.Permission, "CanReadResource")] 
[ClaimRequirement(MyClaimTypes.AnotherPermision, "AnotherClaimVaue")]
//and etc. on a single action.
```

So, imagine how much coding that would take. Ideally, "CanReadResource" is supposed to be a policy that uses many claims to determine if a user can read a resource.

What I do is I create my policies as an enumeration and then loop through and set up the requirements like thus...

```
services.AddAuthorization(authorizationOptions =>
        {
            foreach (var policyString in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Enumerations.Security.Policy)))
            {
                authorizationOptions.AddPolicy(
                    policyString,
                    authorizationPolicyBuilder => authorizationPolicyBuilder.Requirements.Add(new DefaultAuthorizationRequirement((Enumerations.Security.Policy)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enumerations.Security.Policy), policyWrtString), DateTime.UtcNow)));

      /* Note that thisn does not stop you from 
          configuring policies directly against a username, claims, roles, etc. You can do the usual.
     */
            }
        });
```

The DefaultAuthorizationRequirement class looks like...

```
public class DefaultAuthorizationRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public Enumerations.Security.Policy Policy {get; set;} //This is a mere enumeration whose code is not shown.
    public DateTime DateTimeOfSetup {get; set;} //Just in case you have to know when the app started up. And you may want to log out a user if their profile was modified after this date-time, etc.
}

public class DefaultAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<DefaultAuthorizationRequirement>
{
    private IAServiceToUse _aServiceToUse;

    public DefaultAuthorizationHandler(
        IAServiceToUse aServiceToUse
        )
    {
        _aServiceToUse = aServiceToUse;
    }

    protected async override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, DefaultAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
    {
        /*Here, you can quickly check a data source or Web API or etc. 
           to know the latest date-time of the user's profile modification...
        */
        if (_aServiceToUse.GetDateTimeOfLatestUserProfileModication > requirement.DateTimeOfSetup)
        {
            context.Fail(); /*Because any modifications to user information, 
            e.g. if the user used another browser or if by Admin modification, 
            the claims of the user in this session cannot be guaranteed to be reliable.
            */
            return;
        }

        bool shouldSucceed = false; //This should first be false, because context.Succeed(...) has to only be called if the requirement specifically succeeds.

        bool shouldFail = false; /*This should first be false, because context.Fail() 
        doesn't have to be called if there's no security breach.
        */

        // You can do anything.
        await doAnythingAsync();

       /*You can get the user's claims... 
          ALSO, note that if you have a way to priorly map users or users with certain claims 
          to particular policies, add those policies as claims of the user for the sake of ease. 
          BUT policies that require dynamic code (e.g. checking for age range) would have to be 
          coded in the switch-case below to determine stuff.
       */

        var claims = context.User.Claims;

        // You can, of course, get the policy that was hit...
        var policy = requirement.Policy

        //You can use a switch case to determine what policy to deal with here...
        switch (policy)
        {
            case Enumerations.Security.Policy.CanReadResource:
                 /*Do stuff with the claims and change the 
                     value of shouldSucceed and/or shouldFail.
                */
                 break;
            case Enumerations.Security.Policy.AnotherPolicy:
                 /*Do stuff with the claims and change the 
                    value of shouldSucceed and/or shouldFail.
                 */
                 break;
                // Other policies too.

            default:
                 throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /* Note that the following conditions are 
            so because failure and success in a requirement handler 
            are not mutually exclusive. They demand certainty.
        */

        if (shouldFail)
        {
            context.Fail(); /*Check the docs on this method to 
            see its implications.
            */
        }                

        if (shouldSucceed)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement); 
        } 
     }
}
```

Note that the code above can also enable pre-mapping of a user to a policy in your data store. So, when composing claims for the user, you basically retrieve the policies that had been pre-mapped to the user directly or indirectly (e.g. because the user has a certain claim value and that claim value had been identified and mapped to a policy, such that it provides automatic mapping for users who have that claim value too), and enlist the policies as claims, such that in the authorization handler, you can simply check if the user's claims contain requirement.Policy as a Value of a Claim item in their claims. That is for a static way of satisfying a policy requirement, e.g. "First name" requirement is quite static in nature. So, for the example above (which I had forgotten to give example on Authorize attribute in my earlier updates to this answer), using the policy with Authorize attribute is like as follows, where ViewRecord is an enum member:

```
[Authorize(Policy = nameof(Enumerations.Security.Policy.ViewRecord))]
```

A dynamic requirement can be about checking age range, etc. and policies that use such requirements cannot be pre-mapped to users.

An example of dynamic policy claims checking (e.g. to check if a user is above 18 years old) is already at the answer given by @blowdart (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465227/4974715).

PS: I typed this on my phone. Pardon any typos and lack of formatting.

Comment: imho, the Policy is more a static validation procedure with custom logic and currently it cannot be parameterized as easy as it was in old `AuthorizeAttribute`. You have to generate all possible instances of `DefaultAuthorizationRequirement` during app startup to be able to use them in controllers. I would prefer to have one policy that can accept some scalar parameters (potentially infinite combination). This way I don't break Open-Closed principle. And your example does. (anyway I appreciate it)

Comment: @neleus, you have to use a requirement that accepts a resource. For example, in the original question, that resource is the SessionID. In your comment, the resource is the scalar property you're talking about. So, inside the requirement, the resource would be evaluated against the claims of the users and then determine if the authorization should succeed or fail.

Comment: @neleus, already, the user should have been authenticated and also authorized to call the controller action, but the requirement I just described would then be used inside the controller action to determine if the user can go further based on the information contained in the resource provided to it. The resource can come from request headers, query string, data fetched from database, etc. I can write the code if you show interest in such.

Comment: do you mean the specific authorization decisions are rather job of the controller than requirements?

Comment: @neleus Not exactly, you're only calling the code from inside the controller action. But another thing you can do is register IHttpContextAccessor as a service (by services.AddHttpContextAccessor()), and then inject it into the AuthorizationHandler for the Requirement. From IHttpContextAccessor, you can get HttpContext.GetRouteData() and then retrieve the route data you want (e.g. the Seesion ID in the discussion). Beware of nulls.

Comment: I don't really see what this solves. I would personally avoid passing in two things here and just use params to pass in however many permissions enums are required. If you need a ton of permissions passed in then I could see policy creation via these static enums as okay. This isn't that difficult, either you need policies or you don't. There is no "right" way.

Answer (score 6):

As of this writing I believe this can be accomplished with the IClaimsTransformation interface in asp.net core 2 and above.  I just implemented a proof of concept which is sharable enough to post here.

```
public class PrivilegesToClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly IPrivilegeProvider privilegeProvider;
    public const string DidItClaim = "http://foo.bar/privileges/resolved";

    public PrivilegesToClaimsTransformer(IPrivilegeProvider privilegeProvider)
    {
        this.privilegeProvider = privilegeProvider;
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity claimer)
        {
            if (claimer.HasClaim(DidItClaim, bool.TrueString))
            {
                return principal;
            }

            var privileges = await this.privilegeProvider.GetPrivileges( ... );
            claimer.AddClaim(new Claim(DidItClaim, bool.TrueString));

            foreach (var privilegeAsRole in privileges)
            {
                claimer.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role /*"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" */, privilegeAsRole));
            }
        }

        return principal;
    }
}
```

To use this in your Controller just add an appropriate `[Authorize(Roles="whatever")]` to your methods.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("poc")]
[Authorize(Roles = "plugh,blast")]
public JsonResult PocAuthorization()
{
    var result = Json(new
    {
        when = DateTime.UtcNow,
    });

    result.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

    return result;
}
```

In our case every request includes an Authorization header that is a JWT.  This is the prototype and I believe we will do something super close to this in our production system next week.

Future voters, consider the date of writing when you vote.  As of today, this `works on my machine.`™  You will probably want more error handling and logging on your implementation.

Comment: What about ConfigureServices? Is it needed to add something?

Comment: As discussed elsewhere, yes.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple 5-step guide for how to implement custom role authorization using policies for all you copy and pasters out there :) . I used these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Create a requirement:

```
public class RoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Create a handler:

```
public class RoleHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RoleRequirement>
{
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        var requiredRole = requirement.Role;

        //custom auth logic
        //  you can use context to access authenticated user,
        //  you can use dependecy injection to call custom services 

        var hasRole = true;

        if (hasRole)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Fail(new AuthorizationFailureReason(this, $"Role {requirement.Role} missing"));
        }
    }
}
```

Add the handler in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleHandler>();
```

Add a policy with your role requirement in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Read", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new RoleRequirement{Role = "ReadAccess_Custom_System"}));
});
```

Use your policy:

```
[Authorize("Read")]
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Comment: If someone would ever interested, requirement handlers can be registered with any service lifetime, not necessarily singleton. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/dependencyinjection?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Also, if request is unauthorized, result will return exception `No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found` instead of some correct result code. So, 6th step is required: AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler. Good example is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656828/return-http-403-using-authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-core from @Ogglas

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to the great answer from @Shawn. If you are using dotnet 5 you need to update the class to be:

```
public abstract class AttributeAuthorizationHandler<TRequirement, TAttribute> : AuthorizationHandler<TRequirement> where TRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TRequirement requirement)
    {
        var attributes = new List<TAttribute>();
        
        if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var endPoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();

            var action = endPoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();

            if(action != null)
            {
                attributes.AddRange(GetAttributes(action.ControllerTypeInfo.UnderlyingSystemType));
                attributes.AddRange(GetAttributes(action.MethodInfo));
            }
        }
        
        return HandleRequirementAsync(context, requirement, attributes);
    }

    protected abstract Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TRequirement requirement, IEnumerable<TAttribute> attributes);

    private static IEnumerable<TAttribute> GetAttributes(MemberInfo memberInfo) => memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false).Cast<TAttribute>();
}
```

Noting the way getting the ControllerActionDescriptor has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I have bearer token and I can read claims.
I use that attribute on controllers and actions

```
public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string[] Claims;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // check user 
        var contextUser = context?.HttpContext?.User;
        if (contextUser == null)
        {
            throw new BusinessException("Forbidden");
        }


        // check roles
        var roles = contextUser.FindAll("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role").Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
        if (!roles.Any(s => Claims.Contains(s)))
        {
            throw new BusinessException("Forbidden");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

example

```
[CustomAuthorization(Claims = new string[]
    {
        nameof(AuthorizationRole.HR_ADMIN),
        nameof(AuthorizationRole.HR_SETTING)
    })]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SomeAdminController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public SomeAdminController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpGet("list/SomeList")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SomeList()
        => Ok(await _mediator.Send(new SomeListQuery()));
}
```

That is Roles

```
public struct AuthorizationRole
{
    public static string HR_ADMIN;
    public static string HR_SETTING;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For authorization in our app. We had to call a service based on the parameters passed in authorization attribute.

For example, if we want to check if logged in doctor can view patient appointments we will pass "View_Appointment" to custom authorize attribute and check that right in DB service and based on results we will athorize. Here is the code for this scenario:

```
    public class PatientAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
    public PatientAuthorizeAttribute(params PatientAccessRights[] right) : base(typeof(AuthFilter)) //PatientAccessRights is an enum
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { right };
    }

    private class AuthFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        PatientAccessRights[] right;

        IAuthService authService;

        public AuthFilter(IAuthService authService, PatientAccessRights[] right)
        {
            this.right = right;
            this.authService = authService;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var allparameters = context.ActionArguments.Values;
            if (allparameters.Count() == 1)
            {
                var param = allparameters.First();
                if (typeof(IPatientRequest).IsAssignableFrom(param.GetType()))
                {
                    IPatientRequest patientRequestInfo = (IPatientRequest)param;
                    PatientAccessRequest userAccessRequest = new PatientAccessRequest();
                    userAccessRequest.Rights = right;
                    userAccessRequest.MemberID = patientRequestInfo.PatientID;
                    var result = authService.CheckUserPatientAccess(userAccessRequest).Result; //this calls DB service to check from DB
                    if (result.Status == ReturnType.Failure)
                    {
                        //TODO: return apirepsonse
                        context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new AppSystemException("PatientAuthorizeAttribute not supported");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new AppSystemException("PatientAuthorizeAttribute not supported");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And on API action we use it like this:

```
    [PatientAuthorize(PatientAccessRights.PATIENT_VIEW_APPOINTMENTS)] //this is enum, we can pass multiple
    [HttpPost]
    public SomeReturnType ViewAppointments()
    {

    }
```

Comment: Please note that IActionFilter will be a problem when you want to use the same attribute for Hub methods in SignalR.SignalR Hubs expect IAuthorizationFilter

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am not using SignalR in my application  right now so i havent tested it with it.

Comment: Same principle I guess as you will still have to use the header's authorisation entry, the implementation will differ

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people here already told this, but with Policy handlers you can come really far in terms of what you could achieve with the old way in .NET Framework.

I followed a quick writeup from this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61963465/7081176
For me it works flawlessly after making some classes:

The EditUserRequirement:

```
public class EditUserRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public EditUserRequirement()
    {
    }
}
```

An abstract handler to make my life easier:

```
public abstract class AbstractRequirementHandler<T> : IAuthorizationHandler
    where T : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public async Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        var pendingRequirements = context.PendingRequirements.ToList();
        foreach (var requirement in pendingRequirements)
        {
            if (requirement is T typedRequirement)
            {
                await HandleRequirementAsync(context, typedRequirement);
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, T requirement);
}
```

An implementation of the abstract handler:

```
public class EditUserRequirementHandler : AbstractRequirementHandler<EditUserRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, EditUserRequirement requirement)
    {
        // If the user is owner of the resource, allow it.
        if (IsOwner(context.User, g))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static bool IsOwner(ClaimsPrincipal user, Guid userIdentifier)
    {
        return user.GetUserIdentifier() == userIdentifier;
    }
}
```

Registering my handler and requirement:
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, EditUserRequirementHandler>();

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.Policies.EditUser, policy =>
            {
                policy.Requirements.Add(new EditUserRequirement());
            });
        });
```

And then using my Policy in Blazor:

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="@Policies.EditUser" Resource="@id">
    <NotAuthorized>
        <Unauthorized />
    </NotAuthorized>
    <Authorized Context="Auth">
        ...
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I hope this is useful for anyone facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into solving a very similar issue, and settled on creating a custom ActionFilterAttribute (I'm going to call it AuthorizationFilterAttribute) instead of an AuthorizeAttribute to implement the guidance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-6.0#challenge-and-forbid-with-an-operational-resource-handler.