# Multiple AuthorizeAttribute on method fails

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using multiple AuthorizeAttribute on my methods and it's giving me compilation error. This error comes only on build machine and somehow doesn't come on my local machine.

**Rosyln Error CS0579: Duplicate 'AuthorizeAttribute' attribute**

From below SO post, it seems okay to use multiple authorize attribute. I tried adding this on my custom authorize attribute -> [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = true)] but it doesn't seem to work.

[Multiple Authorization attributes on method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272422/multiple-authorization-attributes-on-method)

Is it possible to use multiple authorizeAttribute? If yes, what am I missing?

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
        {
        }


 [MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute (permissions : new[]{"Permission1", "Permission2"})]
 [MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute (permissions : new[]:{"Permission3", "Permission4"})]    
 public string GetSomething(string someId)
        {
        }
```

Comment: In the custom Authorize attributes that I've built, I don't add `[AttributeUsage]`. I'm not sure why that would cause an issue, but try taking it out. Also, the correct usage is `Authorize(Roles = "role1, role2")`.

Comment: Is the colon `:` after `new[]` in the second attribute, `[MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute (permissions : new[]:{"Permission3", "Permission4"})]` meant to be there?

Comment: I do not think you can have new operator in attributes. It has to be something that can be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid any function calls in your attributes. Instead of

```
[MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute (permissions : new[]{"Permission1", "Permission2"})]
```

use code like this:

```
[MyCustomAuthorizeAttribute(permissions: "Permission1,Permission2")]
```

You can split the string in your attributes object.