# Custom System Attribute with if block C#

Tags: c#

Here's roughly what I had in mind:

Class which should get the attribute:

```
 // This should be dynamically - if the if block in the ctor of 
 // AuthorizeAttribute is true here should be 
 // [MyOwn1] if its false [MyOwn2]
[MyOwn]
public class MyClass
{
    // Check
}
```

Class which should give the attribute:

```
public class MyOwnAttribute : Attribute
{

    public AuthorizeAttribute()
    {
        if (SomeMethodOfAnotherClassCheck())
        {
            [MyOwn1];
        {
        else
        } 
            [MyOwn2];
        }
    }

}
```

Now when MyClass asks for the attribute from the MyOwnAttribute class, it should get the correct one depending on the if condition included in the ctor.

I have no idea how to implement this. Can someone help me here please?

Comment: Where does condition come from?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to me, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The condition is just a method of an other class. No inputs or parameters are needed for it.

Comment: is AuthorizeAttribute() a Ctor of MyOwnAttribute?
what is [MyOwn1] and [MyOwn2]?

Comment: @DavidG I like to have the attribute of "MyClass" dynamically. Depending on the if block in the ctor. For sure can put this if block also somewhere else if needed. Its just an idea how it could work

Comment: You can't choose attributes like this, that is why I'm asking what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: You can't at runtime switch the Attribute type that gets instantiated. You can have the implementation of MyOwn attribute behave differently based on a condition but you can't replace it.

Comment: u can't change the type like this, instead, u can add a property in the MyOwnAttribute  (named type for example) and fill it in the if statement

Comment: @rene I like to create more less my own "AuthorizeAttribute" of MVC. I like to give only access to the controller if the user with the mail adress "abc.ab@domain.com" is logged in. If this user is logged in => allow to use controller if not this user => don`t allow user

Comment: In .Net core? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272422/multiple-authorization-attributes-on-method?noredirect=1&lq=1 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071235/overriding-controller-authorizeattribute-for-just-one-action?noredirect=1&lq=1