# Multiple Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webapi, asp.net-authorization

I have ASP.NET web API and I wanted to apply multiple authorization schemes to one controller method.
For my use case, I wanted to allow **Data()** access to all users with **/api/AData** url but only *b_data_user* can access **/api/BData**.

I tried below code and it did not allow to access **/api/AData** for any user. (users are not in *b_data_user*)

I understand this is not ideal way and I should split the **Data()** method and apply two authorization schema for **/api/Adata** and **/api/BData**.

```
[Route("~/api/AData")]
[Route("~/api/BData"), Authorize(Roles = "b_data_user")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Data([FromBody] object[] parameter)
{
    var method = new Uri(Request.RequestUri.ToString()).LocalPath.Replace("/api/", "").ToUpper();
             
    if(method =="AData")
        //No restriction for AData
        // Some logic to call AData
    else if(method =="BData")
        //Only users from b_data_user can access this functionality
        //Some logic to call BData
}
```

Comment: Attributes apply to the method as a whole, not to the attributes they are "grouped" with. Extract the common logic out to a private method and then make two action methods each with different attributes applied that then call the common method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Authorization attributes on method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272422/multiple-authorization-attributes-on-method)