# Authorization base on roles or users in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

Is it possible to have an authorization that will be based on ROles or Users.

Sample:

```
[Authorize(Users = "XXX\\USER1")]
[Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
public class AdminEntityController : Controller
{..code here...}
```

My goal is if the role is admin **OR** the user is XXX\USER1 I will allowed to request in the server. How can I do that?

Comment: These links might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700166/allow-multiple-roles-to-access-controller-action & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754073/building-customauthorization-in-asp-net-mvc/10754108#10754108

Comment: You can use policy based authorization. For checking more than one authorization